# Array length (columns and rows)

Tags: arrays, assembly

Alright, so I script some game in Assembly and trying to get the array length of a defined DB. I use TASM. I know there's this command to find an array length `len equ $-a` but it's not what I specifically need.
For example, my a array looks like this:

```
a DB '0','2','0','2','0','2','0','2'
      DB '2','0','2','0','2','0','2','0'
      DB '0','2','0','2','0','2','0','2'
      DB '1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'
      DB '0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1'
      DB '3','0','3','0','3','0','3','0'
      DB '0','3','0','3','0','3','0','3'
      DB '3','0','3','0','3','0','3','0'
len equ $-a
```

Now, if I use the array command I specified above, it will return 64. What I need is for it to return 8 like the line's number of values.

```
DB '3','0','3','0','3','0','3','0' = 8 values
```

Is that even possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a DB '0','2','0','2','0','2','0','2'
  len equ $-a
  DB '2','0','2','0','2','0','2','0'
  DB '0','2','0','2','0','2','0','2'
  DB '1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'
  DB '0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1'
  DB '3','0','3','0','3','0','3','0'
  DB '0','3','0','3','0','3','0','3'
  DB '3','0','3','0','3','0','3','0'
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Thought of doing it too, but thought it might screw my array.